# Desaturated colours Threlte (three.js)

Tags: three.js, svelte, sveltekit

Trying to generate a skybox, like in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v2eLLBUxQiQ) video, using Threlte but the colours keep appearing desaturated.

Image in vscode:
[image: Texture Image]

Image once a texture:
[imgur link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YQKc.jpg)

+page.svelte:

```
<script>
    import * as Threlte from '@threlte/core';
    import * as Three from 'three';
    import * as Utils from 'three/src/math/MathUtils';

    import tex from '$lib/assets/pana2.jpg';

    // Load the panoramic image and create a texture
    const loader = new Three.TextureLoader();
    const texture = loader.load('/skybox/pana.jpg');

    // Create a spherical geometry and map the texture to it
    const skybox = new Three.SphereGeometry(500, 60, 40);

    // Flip the geometry inside out
    skybox.scale(-1, 1, 1);
</script>

<div class="scene">
    <Threlte.Canvas>
        <!-- Camera -->
        <Threlte.PerspectiveCamera position={{ x: 0, y: 0, z: 0.1 }} fov={75} near={0.1} far={1000}>
            <!-- Controls -->
            <Threlte.OrbitControls autoRotate autoRotateSpeed={0.25} />
        </Threlte.PerspectiveCamera>

        <!-- Lights the scene equally -->
        <Threlte.AmbientLight color={0xffffff} intensity={0.1} />

        <!-- Skybox -->
        <Threlte.Mesh geometry={skybox} material={new Three.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture })} />
    </Threlte.Canvas>
</div>

<style>

    .scene {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        inset: 0;
        background: radial-gradient(hsl(220 14% 20%), hsl(220 20% 10%));
        background-attachment: fixed;
    }
</style>
```

- Tried changing ambient lighting values.
- Tried different light sources.
- Changed image location.
- Used different loading method (useTexture method).

None worked.

Edit:
Desaturation issue caused by image encoding, view answer below for solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a color space issue. Try to define the color space of your loaded texture like so:

```js
texture.encoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
```

This line will tell the renderer that your texture holds color values in the sRGB color space. It is required if Threlte assumes a sRGB color space workflow.